# Bad passphrase for an SSH key (Gerrit tutorial for MediaWiki)

Tags: ssh, mediawiki, wikipedia, gerrit

I'm doing the [Gerrit tutorial](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Gerrit/Tutorial#Add_your_SSH_key) to contribute to Mediawiki, and I'm not sure what to do for this step:

```
Add your private key to the agent (use path to your private key file)
$ ssh-add .ssh/id_rsa
```

When I click <kbd>Enter</kbd>, I'm prompted to enter a passphrase. Am I supposed to enter my private key? If so, where do I find it?

Comment: When you made your key, did you enter a passphrase? If you didn't, you should be able to hit enter at the prompt, entering nothing.

Comment: @GrantHill didn't realize I could do that - thanks!

Comment: If I solved your problem, feel free to accept the answer to help other people with your issue find it. Glad to help!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you didn't type a passphrase when making the private key, you can simply press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: this is good to know but I do think I need to add a password. The problem is when I try to add one I keep getting 'Bad passphrase, try again.' Do you know what I'm supposed to use for this?

Comment: If you want to add a passphrase to a key you've already generated, use `ssh-keygen -p`. See: https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-ssh-key-passphrases/ If you have more questions, you probably want to ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

I've found my private key in the macOS' keychain access app after searching there for "ssh".